# I want to create a condition who check if aria-required attribut is a boolean

Tags: javascript, attributes

I need your help.

i want to check if the attribute `aria-required` contains a boolean

If in the tag with attribut aria-required is not boolean make a alert for example.

I try but...no result

````
    lang: 'fr',
    name: 'test aria',
    query: '[aria-required]',
    filter: function(item){
        if(item.hasAttribute(true) || item.hasAttribute(false)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false
        }
    },
    explanations: 3,
    tags : ['accessibility', 'form', 'aria', 'tags']
}) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely not sure what you meant by this condition ?

```
    if (item.hasAttribute(true) && item.hasAttribute(false)){
        return true;
    }
```

Will this help ?

```
    if (typeof item.getAttribute("aria-required") === "boolean"){
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i want to check if the attribute ```aria-required``` contains a boolean

Comment: Ok I have updated with `getAttribute('aria-required')` if still its not a help then please add some more info